# Is there a name for the default font type used in Java GUI?

Tags: java, user-interface

I want the user of the program I am working on to be able to change the font in the settings. I also want the user to be able to switch back to the default font that is used for all JLabels, JRadioButtons, JTextAreas, etc. Is there a simple name for this font or is there some code that I need to add to get this information? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I think it might be the system default

Comment: It depends on your look and feel (see `UIManager` [getFont](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html#getFont\(java.lang.Object\)) )

Comment: @Duffydake Okay that makes sense. I'm using the nimbus look and feel so I'll check getFont out. Thanks for the reply.